# FindLinearRecurrence is not working for numerical complex number sometimes?

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

First `FindLinearRecurrence` definitely support complex number list, see

```
FindLinearRecurrence[{1. + I, 2. + 0.2 I, 1. + I, 2. + 0.2 I, 1. + I, 
  2. + 0.2 I}]
```

This gives

```
{0., 1. + 0. I}
```

While if you try this (at least in v10.3)

```
list={6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
  6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
  6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
  6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
  6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1};

FindLinearRecurrence[list]
```

No result will be find. Because it gives result the same as input!

```
FindLinearRecurrence[{6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
      6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
      6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
      6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
      6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1}]
```

But `list` is definitely periodic!

Take the real part works fine again,

```
FindLinearRecurrence@Re@list
```

this gives

```
{0., 1.}
```

I think this is possibly a bug for `FindLinearRecurrence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) to convert input lists to exact numbers.

```
list1 = {1. + I, 2. + 0.2 I, 1. + I, 2. + 0.2 I, 1. + I, 2. + 0.2 I};

ker1 = FindLinearRecurrence[list1 // Rationalize]

(*  {0, 1}  *)

list1 == LinearRecurrence[ker1, list1[[1 ;; 2]], Length[list1]]

(*  True  *)

list2 = {6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
   6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
   6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
   6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1, 
   6.683982467191557` - 0.7362491053693563` I, -1};

ker2 = FindLinearRecurrence[list2 //
   Rationalize[#, 0] &]

(*  {0, 1}  *)

list2 == LinearRecurrence[ker2, list2[[1 ;; 2]], Length[list2]]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Oh, actually I tried `Rationalize` before I post. But I didn't know the usage of `Rationalize[expr,0]`, sigh! But, question still remains, do you mean that this is not a bug? After all, all the numbers in `list2` is exactly the same in every digit, and `Re@list2` directly give result. So I still think `FindLinearRecurrence[list2]` should directly give the result without `Rationalize`

Comment: @matheorem - I agree that Mathematica should be able to handle this directly; however, I wouldn't call this limitation a bug. It did not return a wrong answer but rather said in essence to try something else. Some other algorithms that fail with inexact numbers will try with exact numbers and if successful return the result with a message saying that exact numbers were used.

Comment: I still can't agree :) But thank for your solution, working quite well at the moment.